# flask_restful not working with flask.ext.login's login_required decorator

Tags: python, flask-restful

So I'm writing a very basic restful API in flask and the @login_required decorator throws the 'as_view' error. I know it's the decorator because if i comment it out the app runs just fine.  Any thoughts/solutions.  I've tried inheriting UserMixin and Resource inside the User class.  I read somewhere it has to do with Resource as_view being inherited. If it matters I use flask-script to run the app. Thanks guys/girls. Code Below, traceback under code

```
import json

from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, abort, Api, reqparse
from flask.views import MethodView
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user, logout_user, current_user
from lib.mongo import db

from bson.objectid import ObjectId

from crontab import CronTab


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = ''
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
api = Api(app)

##############################################
##############################################
#######USER CLASS FOR LOGGING IN AND OUT
##############################################
##############################################
class User(UserMixin):
  def __init__(self, username, api_key, id, active=True):
    self.username = username
    self.api_key = api_key
    self.id = id
    self.active = active

  def is_active(self):
    account = db.users.find_one({ 'username': self.username, 'api_key': self.api_key})
    if account is not None:
      if not account['username'] == self.username and account['api_key'] == self.api_key:
        self.active = False
    else:
      self.active = False
    return self.active

  def is_anonymous(self):
    return False

  def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

  def get_id(self):
    return str(db.accounts.find_one({ 'username': self.username, 'api_key': self.api_key})['_id'])


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
  user_rec = db.accounts.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(userid)})
  user = User(user_rec['username'], user_rec['api_key'], user_rec['_id'])
  return user


class Auth(Resource):
  def get(self):
    api_key = request.args.get('api_key', '')
    username = request.args.get('username', '')
    if username == '':
      abort(400, message='username was not provided')
    if api_key == '':
      abort(400, message='api key was not provided')

    account = db.accounts.find_one({'username': username, 'api_key': api_key})
    if account:
      if account['account_type'] == 'admin':
        user = User(username, api_key, account['_id'])
        login_user(user)
        return {'auth': 'successful', 'status_code': 200}, 200
      else:
        abort(401, message='you are not an admin')
    else:
       abort(401, message='could not auth account')


@login_required
class ListCronJobs(Resource):
  def get(self):
    cron = CronTab(user=True)
    cronjobs = []
    for line in cron.lines:
      cronjobs.append(line)
    return {'data': cronjobs}


api.add_resource(Auth, '/api/auth')
api.add_resource(ListCronJobs, '/api/listcronjobs')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Traceback:

```
File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/Users/user/folder/app/__init__.py", line 90, in <module>
    api.add_resource(ListCronJobs, '/ListCronJobs/listcronjobs')
  File "/Users/user/folder/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 401, in add_resource
    self._register_view(self.app, resource, *urls, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/user/folder/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask_restful/__init__.py", line 441, in _register_view
    resource_func = self.output(resource.as_view(endpoint, *resource_class_args,
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'
```

EDIT: So I fixed the issue by placing @login_required above the get(self) instead of decorating the class

```
class ListCronJobs(Resource):
  @login_required
  def get(self):
    cron = CronTab(user=True)
    cronjobs = []
    for line in cron.lines:
      cronjobs.append(line)
    return {'data': cronjobs}
```

The new issue is that when I make that request (curl "http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/listcronjobs"
) I get the error: "message": "The server could not verify that you are authorized to access the URL requested.  You either supplied the wrong credentials (e.g. a bad password), or your browser doesn't understand how to supply the credentials required."

I make the request after I auth in with curl

Answer (score 0):

So this the working version.

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, abort, Api
from flask.ext.login import LoginManager, UserMixin, login_required, login_user#, logout_user, current_user
from lib.mongo import db

from bson.objectid import ObjectId

from crontab import CronTab


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = 'm\\x88\xe2@\xb18\\x82\xa9\x7f\\x84l[G\x8d\xe6N\x8fJl\\x95{\xd2F\\x10'
login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.init_app(app)
api = Api(app)

##############################################
##############################################
#######USER CLASS FOR LOGGING IN AND OUT
##############################################
##############################################
class User(UserMixin):
  def __init__(self, username, api_key, id, active=True):
    self.username = username
    self.api_key = api_key
    self.id = id
    self.active = active

  def is_active(self):
    account = db.users.find_one({ 'username': self.username, 'api_key': self.api_key})
    if account is not None:
      if not account['username'] == self.username and account['api_key'] == self.api_key:
        self.active = False
    else:
      self.active = False
    return self.active

  def is_anonymous(self):
    return False

  def is_authenticated(self):
    return True

  def get_id(self):
    return str(db.accounts.find_one({ 'username': self.username, 'api_key': self.api_key})['_id'])


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(userid):
  user_rec = db.accounts.find_one({'_id': ObjectId(userid)})
  user = User(user_rec['username'], user_rec['api_key'], user_rec['_id'])
  return user


class Auth(Resource):
  def get(self):
    api_key = request.args.get('api_key', '')
    username = request.args.get('username', '')
    if username == '':
      abort(400, message='username was not provided')
    if api_key == '':
      abort(400, message='api key was not provided')

    account = db.accounts.find_one({'username': username, 'api_key': api_key})
    if account:
      if account['account_type'] == 'admin':
        user = User(username, api_key, account['_id'])
        login_user(user)
        return {'auth': 'successful', 'status_code': 200}, 200
      else:
        abort(401, message='you are not an admin')
    else:
       abort(401, message='could not auth account')



class ListCronJobs(Resource):
  @login_required
  def get(self):
    cron = CronTab(user=True)
    cronjobs = []
    for line in cron.lines:
      cronjobs.append(line)
    return {'data': cronjobs}

api.add_resource(Auth, '/api/auth')
api.add_resource(ListCronJobs, '/api/listcronjobs')

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

Instead of running the test with curl I ran them with python's requests module and created a session.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
res = s.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/auth?username=foo&api_key=bar')
print res.json()
res = s.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/listcronjobs')
print res.json()
```

When using curl to auth in the session wasn't kept, so the API call to list the cronjobs was rejected.